# Specify username and group in Hadoop Java API?

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to access HDFS files using specific user in specific group. I know how to specify a user as in given code:

```
UserGroupInformation ugi
                = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

     public Void run() throws Exception {

     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/user/hbase");
     conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");
     FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
     fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));
     FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hbase"));
     for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
     }
     return null;
   }
 });
```

So I need to specify the group name as well. How can I specify the group name along with the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop groups are determined by Hadoop Username Group Mapping as described [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#Group_Mapping)